# Are Swift's String, Array, and Dictionary NSObjects? Why can a struct be an NSObject?

Tags: swift, cocoa, cocoa-touch, toll-free-bridging

I use `NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(obj)` to transform an object to `NSData`. The `archivedDataWithRootObject(obj)` method require its parameter to be an `NSObject`, conforming to `NSCoding`.

I tried archiving Swift `String`s, `Array`s, and `Dictionary`s, and it worked well. So I think `String` is an `NSObject` conforming to `NSCoding`.

I also checked this code in a playground, to confirm that `String` is an `NSObject`:

```
var str = "Hello, playground"
let isObject = (str is NSObject) // isObject is true
```

But when I navigate to `String`'s definition (with Cmd + Click), it shows that `String` is a `struct`. I cannot find the code showing that `String` is an `NSObject`.

```
public struct String {
    /// An empty `String`.
    public init()
}
```

So, why in the `String` definition, can't I find the code showing that `String` is an `NSObject`? And why can a struct be an `NSObject`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`String`, `Array`, `Dictionary` are all bridged to their Objective-C counterparts (`NSString`, `NSArray` and `NSDictionary`) and can seamlessly act like so.

String itself does not inherit from `NSObject` and is actually a struct but it is bridged from `NSString` which does. When you use a (Swift) `String` in your code it can act like an `NSString` thus giving you the output from the code you provided.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. Can you help me how can I create a MyString struct, it bridge to NSString, as swift String struct did?

Comment: @huync that behaviour is built into the swift language you wont be able to create your own struct and bridge it with NSString... if the reason you want to do is so you can use `NSKeyedArchiver` youre better off simply making a class that inherits from `NSString` or `NSObject`

Comment: @BlakeLockley Any resources to gain knowledge about how how bridging is done between types such as NSString and String? Like the technical process involved in it? +1 though.

Comment: @AkshanshThakur try these https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithObjective-CAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH4-ID35